# RequireJs and global class

Tags: variables, requirejs, global

In my page i initiate a class using requireJs

```
define('MyClass', [], function() {
    var MyClass = new Class({
        initialize: function() {
            ...
        }   
    });

    return MyClass;
});


require(['MyClass'], function(MyClass) {
    var myClass = new MyClass();
});
```

The problem is that i want to access myClass variable in some other js code but the myClass variable is not global. How is the right way of exposing the myClass variable to some other js code ?

Answer (score 1):

One point of requireJS is to avoid global variables. If you need only one instance of `MyClass`, the module could return the instance instead of the class.

```
define('MyClass', [], function() {
    var MyClass = new Class({
        initialize: function() {
            ...
        }   
    });

    return new MyClass();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**In general you should not leak variables in the global space.**

If the other code you are talking about is an AMD-style module (RequireJS modules are generally AMD-style modules) then you should export the `myClass` instance just like you export the `MyClass` class in your question. You already know how to do it.

If you *must* interface with code that does not play well with RequireJS, you should be able to just remove the `var` keyword to leak your data:

```
require(['MyClass'], function(MyClass) {
    myClass = new MyClass();
});
```

This should leak `myClass` into the global space.

If your code is embedded inside a function, it might hit a variable defined in a higher scope, but you can do this:

```
function () {
    // This function has a local `myClass`. You could rewrite it or...
    var myClass = new Whatever();

    ...
    require(['MyClass'], function(MyClass) {
        // ... you can leak your data like this.
       window.myClass = new MyClass();
    });
}
```